# Routing only internal traffic to VPN

Tags: vpn, linux-networking

When I connect to the VPN, I don't have access to the internal addresses of my office.

If I issue a: `route add default dev ppp0`

I can finally ping the office's machines but all my internet traffic doesn't work.

How can I route just office traffic (E.G. 10.20.X.X) to the office VPN and the rest of the traffic to my normal internet gateway?

Side note: Would be appreciated a link to a quick guide to understand routes/gateways to be able to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ip command, from [iproute2](http://linux-ip.net/html/tools-ip-route.html) tools.
To access 10.20.1.0/24 vpn network

> ip route add 10.20.1.0/24 dev ppp0

Comment: I get: Error: ??? prefix is expected rather than "10.20.x.x/16".

Comment: I guess that should be 10.20.0.0?

Comment: Yes, 10.20.0.0/16 works